# Python Pygame score display

Tags: python, pygame, display

I am trying to display a score on screen in Pygame.

Here is the text function. When executed, it displays "**AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'get'"*
Thanks for the help!

```
   def text(self, surface, text, size, x, y):
          font= pg.font.Font(self.font_name, size)
          text_surface = font.render(text, True, WHITE )
          text_rect= text_surface.get.rect()
          text.rect.midtop = (x,y)
          self.screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
```

Answer (score 4):

You meant `text_surface.get_rect()`, not `text_surface.get.rect()`.

Also, looking ahead in your function, you probably meant `text_rect` instead of `text.rect`.